# Helpdesk Template - See My Service Requests in My Site

Tags: intranet, my-site, site-template

I have set up the Helpdesk 'fantastic 40' template on our portal and can add service requests etc.

I can also see that in the site's child pages I have access to a whole lot of web parts such as 'Requests assigned to me' etc.

What I would like to do however is make it so users can see the open requests they have raised on their MySite page. This sits on another web application. 
e.g. My helpdesk template is at /sharepoint:8083/helpdesk and the mysites are at /sharepoint:8090

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some JQuery magic to pull through a view on this data into your MySites.  Take a look at the [JQuery Library for SharePoint Web Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

No need for Thanks Marc, thought I'd get there before you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MOSS you may be able to do some things with the Site Aggregator web part which can pull documents and tasks associated with the user.  This view is limited in my experience.

There are some third part tools that can help you pull that data together across web apps and site collections.

Another option is to build a custom display.  All of the SharePoint list data is available via web services so you can point to the Helpdesk site and display the data either in a DataView or Custom Web Part.